# which features in Sitecore depend on the page editor working?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

I remember from my Sitecore (7) training that there are a few of the newer features which are designed to be used through the page editor. I can remember some of the personalisation stuff and multivariate testing for example. Can anyone tell me what the full range of features that hang off the page editor are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to think of any that are solely Page Editor only. You can look after personalisation and multivariate testing from within the Content Editor as well. The main difference being that the Page Editor gives your content authors an easier and more directed user experience because if you configure it nicely, you can ensure that content can only be added/sourced from a particular location in your content tree and that the content added/sourced from that location is only of one specific template type (as one example). This assists the user when adding/editing content and saves them an extra 3 or 4 clicks and pop up windows typically ;)